# Is ADF Venturis based on an established typeface?

Tags: typefaces

I'm just curious, since I've started using the venturis package with pdfLaTeX. I haven't been able to find much information about its provenance, unlike most of the other 'plug and play' LaTeX fonts. Thanks!

*edit:* I have already looked at [ADF's website](http://arkandis.tuxfamily.org/tugfonts.htm), but it doesn't give much detail.

*edit 2:* There's also the [venturis package documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/venturisadf/doc/fonts/venturisadf), which indicates that the fonts "were developed by Hirwen Harendal of the Arkandis Digital Foundry." Maybe that's good enough as an answer. If they had based it on an older typeface, there would probably be some indication. Anyway, if nobody chimes in soon, this question can probably be closed.

Comment: The licence says they are based on (significantly modified) Utopia fonts – the ones Adobe kindly allowed TUG to distribute.

Comment: From `venturisadf.pdf`: "The fonts are based on Adobe’s Utopia". And the readme says: "As
the Software is modified from Utopia fonts, they are under the same license as
the Utopia fonts themselves"